# Spring security authentication with username only but without password and I need to generate token if login success

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security

I need to generate the token based on authentication without password but we should give username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used spring security builtin class to get the user

authenticated by knowing only the username.

Here is my code,

Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userObj.getUserId(), "",
                grantedAuthorities);

Comment: Can you share the value for the "grantedAuthorities" value?